# How to use hjkl keys as arrow keys in contextual menus in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

I am using `vscodevim` extension with Visual Studio Code.

I would love to use `hjkl` keys as arrow keys in contextual menus, specially for the `intellisense`.

Any idea how to enable this option?

If `vscodevim` extension does not support this feature, which shortcut can be used to move the cursor within the contextual menu without touching the arrow keys?

Comment: https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/2886

Answer (score 3):

I have been looking for a way to do this (like Vim or Neovim J/K/L/M ), without installing any extension. I found a configuration on github, [here](https://gist.github.com/espenbjorkeng/484871484d4bf13ce23d8d115e2e8ef5)

Just copy and paste ( with comments ) in the keybindings.json file of VS Code , icon on the top right or [here](https://dev.to/taoliu12/how-to-open-keybindings-json-in-vscode-5a9h#:%7E:text=You%20can%20also%20open%20the,Keyboard%20Shortcuts%20(JSON)%20command).

You can also use a Jumpy extension to complement this configuration [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=jumpy&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
{
  "key": "h",
  "command": "selectNextSuggestion",
  "when": "suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
}
```

and

```
{
  "key": "l",
  "command": "selectPrevSuggestion",
  "when": "suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
}
```

Or whichever keys you wish to use.  Those keybindings will cycle through the intellisense suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your VSCode `keybindings.json` file:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+k",
    "command": "selectPrevSuggestion",
    "when": "suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+j",
    "command": "selectNextSuggestion",
    "when": "suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
},
```

Credit goes to @GibboK for the [link](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/2886) to this answer in a comment, above.